# Adding the_content() return warning count()

Tags: theme-development

I'm using `the_content()` function for elementor plugin implement, but warning comes up once I use this function:

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
> implements Countable

How can I fix this count() warning?

Comment: I noticed the same problem, I guess it's an Elementor/WP problem you can't fix.

Comment: @ralphsmit so how does other themes have Elementor working without any other issue? they disable php warnings?

Comment: True, they disable the WP_Debug in the wp-config.php. If you check the location of the error message (`wp-includes/post-template.php`) you can see that it is an error in a WP file. You are not responsible for the wp-includes folder, so my guess is that the Elementor developers should fix this. Btw, normal users don't have PHP warnings enabled in the first place (and as far as I know the Elementor plugin works normal). Plus, it's a `warning` and not an `error`.

Comment: @ralphsmit You should write this in answer, while researching I didn't found any answer that explain it like you did. might be useful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed this error myself too when using the Elementor plugin. It is only displayed when `WP_Debug` is set to `true`.

The location of the warning is `wp-includes/post-template.php`. This is not a theme location, so the short version is that you're not responsible for it.

The error only appears when using Elementor. I think that the Elementor developers should fix this error, because it is their plugin that 'conflicts' with a `wp-includes` file. I expect that this will be fixed in a future version of Elementor.

My conclusion is that you can ignore this error message. It is only visible when WP_Debug is `true` and normal users seldom enable this. Plus, it is only a `warning` and not an `error`. As far as I know, the Elementor plugin is not hindered by it. (However, this could turn into an `error` in a future version of PHP when it is not fixed.) But for now you shouldn't worry.

**UPDATE PER 15/7/2020:**

This error is caused by only using `the_content()` function outside of a loop. This function should be put inside a loop.

So replace

```
the_content();
```

with

```
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
```

Replacing this made the error disappear, while my content and everything didn't change. My guess now is that the `count()` function has to do sth with the wp count in the loop.

Comment: Mentioned in an article about [using `the_content()` for beginners](https://ralphjsmit.com/explanation-of-the_content-gutenberg-elementor/).